# twisted - is Factory object thread safe?

Tags: python, multithreading, twisted

Following code listen on 2 port, when there is message modify a global dict object. And there is a timer will modify dict also.

```
d = {}
class x(Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        # according to data call x's function
        self.f()
    def f(self):
        global d
        d['x'] = 'x'
class y(Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        # according to data call y's function
        self.f()
    def f(self):
        global d
        d['y'] = 'y'
def modify_d():
    global d
    for k in d.keys():
        if d[k] == 'whatever':
             del d[k]
reactor.listenTCP(8880, x())
reactor.listenTCP(8881, y())
lc = task.LoopingCall(modify_d)
lc.start(300)
reactor.run()
```

Do I need add lock around d when access it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not thread safe, but that doesn't matter.  You don't need a lock.  Twisted runs all of your callbacks (excepting those which involve an API that specifically mentions threading) in the same, main, I/O thread, so you don't have to worry about multiple things running at the same time.